# HTTP/Wi-Fi controlled AC plug socket

Tags: smart-plugs

I am looking for an AC plug/socket, ideally Israel/EU standard, that can be controlled by http. I have an Arduino with enet connected to my WiFi router that will be in charge of controlling the socket. This is for the bathroom IR heater which I often forget to turn off :(

Comment: My guess is the easiest would be to go for something which connects to a Google Home or Alexa... it all depends how much trouble you want to go to / how much you are willing to spend.  You can make a [DIY plug based on an ESP](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/diy-smart-plug-using-esp8266) if you want absolute control; alternatively you can go for [something cheap and simple](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-eu-smart-plug-google-home.html) which you may only be able to control with proprietary hardware.

Comment: install a timer switch

Comment: Thanks, it was while searching a countdown socket that i found all theses new wifi sockets and thought it'd be more flexible and homogeneous: The lower level bathroom heater is controlled by Arduino

Answer (score 2):

I find the shelly line of devices quite handy:
https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-plug-s-smart-home-automation-device/

They have an open, documented REST api:
https://shelly-api-docs.shelly.cloud/
and might even be able to handle the required task by themselves through countdown-timer settings or comsumption thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

https://sonoff.tech/products/

if the default firmware doesn't fit your needs you can flash your own onto them:

https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota

https://esphome.io/

https://www.letscontrolit.com/wiki/index.php/ESPEasy

cheers

Comment: Welcome to the site! It would be much better to include the model name of the suggested product rather than just links, since with time, links can break. You can take the [tour] to earn a badge and visit the [help] for more details on how this site works.